# How do I to manipulate StackLayout to visible true or false?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android

I am trying to manipulate a stacklayout but I cannot getting its name on controller to change it visible or not. How can I do that, is it works on Xamarin ?

**Trying**

```
<ContentPage.Content>

    <StackLayout HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" Padding="2">

        <StackLayout HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand">
            <Label Text="Compre agora seu número da sorte" 
                   FontSize="Small" 
                   TextColor="Gray"
                   FontAttributes="Bold"  
                   HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand"
                   />
        </StackLayout>

        <StackLayout HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand">
            <Label Text="Concurso" FontAttributes="Bold"></Label>
            <Label x:Name="idConcurso"></Label>
            <Label Text="Prêmio" FontAttributes="Bold"></Label>
            <Label x:Name="premioNome"></Label>                
        </StackLayout>

        <StackLayout HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand">
            <ListView x:Name="GridNumerosDaSorte"
                        SeparatorVisibility="Default" 
                        HasUnevenRows="true"    
                        ItemAppearing="OnItemAppearing"
                        >

                <ListView.Header>
                    <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal" BackgroundColor="#335D3B">
                        <Label Text="Nº da Sorte" TextColor="#FFF" HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand" ></Label>
                        <Label Text="Valor(R$)" TextColor="#FFF"    HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand" ></Label>
                        <Label Text="Controle"  TextColor="#335D3B" HorizontalOptions="EndAndExpand" ></Label>
                    </StackLayout>
                </ListView.Header>

                <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <ViewCell>

                            <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="0,10,0,0">
                                <Label Text="{Binding numero}"  HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand"></Label>
                                <Label Text="{Binding valor, StringFormat='{}{0:N}'}" HorizontalOptions="EndAndExpand" ></Label>
                                <Button Text="Comprar" Clicked="OnComprarClick" CommandParameter="{Binding .}"  HorizontalOptions="EndAndExpand" BackgroundColor="Orange"></Button>
                            </StackLayout>

                        </ViewCell>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListView.ItemTemplate>

            </ListView>

        </StackLayout>

        <StackLayout x:Name="FooterPanel" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" IsVisible="False">
            <Label Text="text 1" HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand"></Label>
            <Label Text="text 2" HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand"></Label>
            <Label Text="text 3" HorizontalOptions="EndAndExpand"></Label>
        </StackLayout>



    </StackLayout>

</ContentPage.Content>
```

**Controller**

```
//x:Name does not appear on controller, it does not works
FooterPanel.isVisible = true;
```

Comment: is FooterPanel contained in a DataTemplate?

Comment: Not, it isn't ..

Comment: What do you mean with the Controller? Are you talking about the code-behind (*.xaml.cs) file?

Comment: try stopping visual studio, delete all bin/obj folders from your projects, and restart VS

Comment: @Jason I edited the post with my  .xaml complete

Comment: You need to save the code in xaml (ctrl+s) before you access the element in xaml.cs file .

Comment: your XAML is fine, the tooling is not generating some support files.  Try doing as I suggested to force VS to update these files

Comment: it works. I did @Jason suggestion. start and stop VS and it works.